# State not rebuilding inside dialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code where I have a dropdown where a user can select some options, the problem is after selecting it the new value does not appear. I tried using setState for something else and it works outside the page of the dialog but nothing rebuilds inside the dialog.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../variables.dart';

class HomePageTeacher extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageTeacher({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePageTeacher> createState() => _HomePageTeacherState();
}

class _HomePageTeacherState extends State<HomePageTeacher> {
  String name = "//name of user//"; // Replace with name of user
  String? selectedVal;
  static const menuItems = [
    "Info",
    "Urgent",
  ];
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _popUpItems = menuItems
      .map((String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          ))
      .toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Add Update",
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context){
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Input Text'),
                content: const TextField(
                  maxLength: 200,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter text'),
                ),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedVal,
                    hint: const Text("Type of Message"),
                    items: _popUpItems,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      if (newValue != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedVal = newValue;
                          debugPrint(selectedVal);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
```

Set State works outside the dialog but for some reason doesn't inside the dialog.

Comment: wrap you dialog with `statefullBuilder` and use local `setState` to update the widget inside the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the Dropdown buttom with a StatefullBuilder
Like :

```
 StatefullBuilder(builder:(context,state){
return DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedVal,
                    hint: const Text("Type of Message"),
                    items: _popUpItems,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      if (newValue != null) {
                        state(() {
                          selectedVal = newValue;
                          debugPrint(selectedVal);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the **state** will rebuild inside the **showDialog** widget, because when you do **showDialog** it makes a new route and push it onto the navigation stack it remains on the screen until you close/pop it. This is actually in a separate route. so when you do the setState will not affect anything to the parent widget that calls the **showDialog**.

So I suggest you to make a separate widget to handle the state changes and show it from the **showDialog**.

```
class _HomePageTeacherState extends State<HomePageTeacher> {
  String name = "//name of user//"; // Replace with name of user
  String? selectedVal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Add Update",
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return UpdateDialog(
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedVal = newValue;
                    debugPrint(selectedVal);
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpdateDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String?> onChanged;

  const UpdateDialog({required this.onChanged, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateDialogState createState() => _UpdateDialogState();
}

class _UpdateDialogState extends State<UpdateDialog> {
  static const menuItems = ["Info", "Urgent"];
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Input Text'),
      content: TextField(
        maxLength: 200,
        maxLines: null,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter text'),
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedValue,
          hint: const Text("Type of Message"),
          items: menuItems.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = newValue!;
              widget.onChanged(newValue!);
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```