# flutter showCupertinoModalPopup (date picker) with bloc state does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, bottom-sheet, state-management

i am stuck in a situtation where the state is being emitted but the UI is not updating i have checked the code it is updating the list.

cubit class method

```
void showDatePicker(context, index) async {
    DateTime date = DateTime.now();
    await showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.25,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                  onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
                    date = value;
                  },
                  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                ),
              ),
              CupertinoButton(
                child: const Text('Done'),
                onPressed: () {
                  String formattedTime = DateFormat.jm().format(date);
                  var updatedList = state.listOfDailyRoutineOption;
                  updatedList[index].time = formattedTime;
                  emit(state.copyWith(listOfDailyRoutineOption: updatedList));
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

cubit state class

```
part of 'on_board_cubit.dart';

class OnBoardState extends Equatable {
  const OnBoardState({
    this.currentPage = 0,
    this.listOfDailyRoutineOption = const [],
  });

  final int currentPage;
  final List<DailyRoutineModel> listOfDailyRoutineOption;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [currentPage, listOfDailyRoutineOption];

  OnBoardState copyWith({
    int? currentPage,
    List<DailyRoutineModel>? listOfDailyRoutineOption,
  }) {
    return OnBoardState(
      currentPage: currentPage ?? this.currentPage,
      listOfDailyRoutineOption:
          listOfDailyRoutineOption ?? this.listOfDailyRoutineOption,
    );
  }
}
```

ui

```
class DailyRouteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DailyRouteWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DailyRouteWidget> createState() => _DailyRouteWidgetState();
}

class _DailyRouteWidgetState extends State<DailyRouteWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<OnBoardCubit>(context).onAddDailyRoutine();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocConsumer<OnBoardCubit, OnBoardState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: ListView(children: [
              const Text("Daily Routine", style: header3Style),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text("At what time do you do the following:", style: label),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Column(
                  children: List.generate(state.listOfDailyRoutineOption.length,
                      (index) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      state.listOfDailyRoutineOption[index].title,
                      style: label,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: MyElevatedButton(
                        borderRadius: 50,
                        width: size.width * 0.1,
                        height: size.height * 0.03,
                        buttonColor: btnColor,
                        buttonText: state.listOfDailyRoutineOption[index].time,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<OnBoardCubit>(context)
                            .showDatePicker(context, index),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }))
            ]));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The bottom sheet popup correctly the time is set for the daily routine even though it is printed but the UI is not updating. i have also called the emit state in .then of showCupertinoBottomSheet
even though the statefulbuilder does not work

SS of UI
[image: UI]
[image: bottom sheet]

Comment: Hey, I think your issue could be same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76666538/state-not-rebuilding-inside-dialog/76667695#76667695

Comment: hello @DewaPrabawa thanks for the help, but mine is different as I am doing it with a bloc pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. It's not recommended to store or pass an instance of `BuildContext` outside the `Widget` because  it may become invalid
   if the widget it is associated with is unmounted from the widget tree. Check [BuildContext](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html)
2. Your cubit has dependency on Flutter framework (cupertino in particular). But cubit shouldn't know about any Framework classes (Widgets, Navigators and etc.) at all as it only contains a business logic not related to application or presentation layers.
3. Your cubit has now more than one responsibility: it's not only managing states but also start to be responsible for routing and displaying UI (showCupertinoModalPopup). This breaks [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

In your particular case there two variants possible:

1. Display bottom sheet in you `_DailyRouteWidgetState` directly as a reaction on `MyElevatedButton` onPressed event.
2. Let your cubit to decide how to react on user tap event. In that case call cubit `onShowDatePickerPressed` and as a reaction just emit `DisplayDatePicker` or `DatePickerRequired` state, listen that state with `BlocListener` inside `_DailyRouteWidgetState` and call `showCupertinoModalPopup` as a reaction for that state. Here is [a good example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesfluttershowsnackbar) from `flutter_bloc` library documentation. This implementation require more code but has a better separation of concerns and allow to easily cover your logic with cubit and widget tests.